# Plato's understanding of passion

Tags: comparative-religion, western-philosophy

What would Buddhists say in response to the statement by Plato in [The Republic Book IV](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/republic.5.iv.html):

> And are there not many other cases in which we observe that when a
> man's desires violently prevail over his reason, he reviles himself,
> and is angry at the violence within him, and that in this struggle,
> which is like the struggle of factions in a State, his spirit is on
> the side of his reason;

> You remember that passion or spirit appeared at first sight to be a
> kind of desire, but now we should say quite the contrary; for in the
> conflict of the soul, spirit (passion) is arrayed on the side of the
> rational principle (reason).

I have some ideas but I would like some other opinions.  I'm primarily interested in the second paragraph, and not so much regarding the concept of soul.  Just to clear up my assumption, I equate reason to be the same as Buddhist concept of intellect.

It seems true, but is it just morality? Even morality is reason no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both speak of reason and intellect and wisdom and knowledge (and a host of other topics) they are all conceptualised very differently.
For Plato, reasoning is the highest and best and that which makes humans unique.
While reasoning is also held to be of importance by Buddhists, it is conceptualised not in terms of essential logic of is and is-not nor ontologically, which for Plato is a realm of forms (and this form is so very different from the forms used in Buddhist context) but rather as a relative and conventional form of thinking.

WHat are the consequences of having these differences? A very prominent difference is the following- Plato never goes onto explicitly talk about what is desire or what is wisdom except passing comments. And his dialogical reasoning is what one may call Platonic dialect. He certainly does not speak of compassion. This is not only about Republic, but in general about any of the other Platonic texts. Buddhists on the other hand, make compassion a core and have important distinctions in reasoning and wisdom, interms of characteristics and gradations of development.

Comment: isn't justice the highest and best for Plato?

Comment: Yes @blue_hefe. Justice is highest for Plato, when he is speaking about Society and how it is to be governed. For one, the way to get to justice is through reason. For another, when i said that I meant, not in the sphere of society, but in what makes humans unique and special. But also highest in regards of being over and above base instincts.